# Is it possible to obtain specific message offset in Kafka+SparkStreaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to obtain and store the offset for a specific message in Kafka by using Spark Direct Stream.
Looking at the Spark documentation is simple to obtain the range offsets for each partition but what I need is to store the start offset for each message of a topic after a full scan of the queue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use [MessageAndMetadata](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils.html#createDirectStream(org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext,%20scala.collection.immutable.Map,%20scala.collection.immutable.Map,%20scala.Function1,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag)) version of `createDirectStream`  which allows you to access `message metadata`.

You can find example here which returns Dstream of `tuple3`.

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(10))

val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> (kafkaBroker))
var fromOffsets = Map[TopicAndPartition, Long]()
val topicAndPartition: TopicAndPartition = new TopicAndPartition(kafkaTopic.trim, 0)
val topicAndPartition1: TopicAndPartition = new TopicAndPartition(kafkaTopic1.trim, 0)
fromOffsets += (topicAndPartition -> inputOffset)
fromOffsets += (topicAndPartition1 -> inputOffset1)

val messagesDStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder, Tuple3[String, Long, String]](ssc, kafkaParams, fromOffsets, (mmd: MessageAndMetadata[String, String]) => {
    (mmd.topic ,mmd.offset, mmd.message().toString)
  })
```

In above example `tuple3._1` will have `topic`, `tuple3._2` will have `offset` and `tuple3._3` will have `message`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I'm right in this way I'll be able to read from a specific offset.. I'm still wondering if there is a simple way to compute the start offset of each  message within a partition. What I need is to store the offset for each message and then use this code to read a specific message. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you were right but with above code you will also get offset associated with each message in `messagesDStream`. I mean `createDirectStream` gives you `Dstream` of `Tuple3` and in each tuple you will get `topic-name` and `message` and its associated `offset`.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for the late response.. It's working. However I'm assuming tha "fromOffset" is the start offset from which scan the partition. Thank you very much avr

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct. `fromOffset` is the starting offset from where consumer starts reading.

Comment: how do you manage offsets though, so I put inputOffset 0, but I let my spark streaming app run, and than it crashes it will start at 0 again correct?

Comment: There are several ways to manage offsets `1.` using spark checkpointing 2. writing offsets at the end of each batch into fault tolerant file systems like s3, HDFS or dbs like cassandra or HBase. I'm using the latter.

Comment: Hi, avr do you know if it is possible to get even the timestamp for each message?

Comment: @theMadKing If I've understood your point you need to use a simple Kafka Consumer in order to obtain the offset range

Comment: @avr it seems this method is not available in spark-streaming-kafka-0-10 version, can you help me how to get this done in newer version ?