# Spark-Stream Differentiating Kafka Topics

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

If I feed my Spark-Streaming Application more than one topic like so:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))
    val topics = Set("raw_1", "raw_2)
    val kafkaParams = Map("metadata.broker.list" -> "localhost:9092")
    val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topics)
```

When I run my application how can I figure out from my stream what the difference between which topic it is pulling from? Is there a way to do? If I do something like

```
val lines = stream.print()
```

I am getting nothing of differentiation. Is the only way to do it to make the Kafka Message Key a denoting factor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [MessageAndMetadata](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils.html#createDirectStream(org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext,%20scala.collection.immutable.Map,%20scala.collection.immutable.Map,%20scala.Function1,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag)) version of `createDirectStream` which allows you to access message metadata.

You can find example implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37573596/5936696) .